# Getting the mean without having the total population

Tags: probability, statistics, solution-verification

I have the following question:

> $10$% of applications for a job possess the right skills. A company has
> 3 positions to fill and they interview applicants one at a time until
> they fill all $3$ positions. The company takes $3$ hours to interview an
> unqualified applicant and $5$ hours to interview a qualified applicant.
> Calculate the mean of the time to conduct all interviews.

I got a bit lost considering that they wanted to mean of **all** interviews however I just did $0.10*3+0.90*5=3.2$ which seemed too simplistic, any help in correction/verification would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe a good idea to start with a (slightly) simpler problem.  Suppose the firm only needs to hire one (qualified) applicant.  How many hours is that expected to take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we can note that, no matter how many applicants are interviewed, $3$ qualified applicants will be interviewed, taking a total of $3*5=15$ hours.

Next, we need to find how many unqualified applicants are interviewed. Since each applicant can be assumed to be independently equally likely to be qualified, and you stop interviewing after a fixed number of qualified applicants, the number of unqualified applicants interviewed is given by a [Negative Binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) random variable, with parameters $p=0.9$ (the probability of an unqualified candidate) and $r=3$ (the number of qualified candidates). The mean of this is given by $\dfrac{pr}{1-p}=\dfrac{0.9*3}{1-0.9}=27$.

Therefore, the mean time taken for all interviews is $3$ hours for each unqualified candidate plus $5$ hours for each qualified candidate, giving a total of
$$27*3 + 3*5 = 96$$

Comment: thank you, alll clear!

Answer (score 0):

I think you were assuming that only one interview was done.

What happens if the company conducts interviews until 3 qualified applicants are found ?

Comment: No idea how to do this since the total number isn't mentioned, maybe 0.10*3*5+0.9*3?